# How Google Earth Pro computes the projection of GeoTIFF files

Tags: geotiff-tiff, google-earth, kmz, esri-ascii-raster

I got an elevation dataset in .asc, I wanted to display it into Google Earth Pro so I made a Python script to convert it into GeoTIFF.

To my demise importing all the GeoTIFF at once only displays the last one; I have to import them one by one.

I notice that when Importing a GeoTIFF, Google Earth Pro does projection transformation. If you look at this image you will notice that the image is not in the orientation of the original bounding box

[image: doing some automated reprojection (plane to sphere?)]

If I add them one by one they perfectly line up

[image: imported one by one]

Then I added code to my script to make a KMZ out of all those GeoTIFF so I could import them in one click, however I had to convert the coordinate from Lambert93 to WGS84, and by doing so Google Earth Pro won't do the projection correction anymore giving me this:

[image: my KMZ]

How can I compute this reprojection computation in order to make a working KMZ?

The dataset is taken from here :

https://geoservices.ign.fr/bdalti (it's BDALTIV2_2-0_25M_ASC_LAMB93-IGN69_D014_2022-12-21)

and my Python code is like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import simplekml
import zipfile
import pyproj

source_folder = r"C:\checkout2\common-scripts\brgm\geoportail_carte_relief\source_files\BDALTIV2_2-0_25M_ASC_LAMB93-IGN69_D014_2022-12-21\BDALTIV2_2-0_25M_ASC_LAMB93-IGN69_D014_2022-12-21\BDALTIV2\1_DONNEES_LIVRAISON_2023-03-00115\BDALTIV2_MNT_25M_ASC_LAMB93_IGN69_D014"
output_folder = os.path.join(source_folder, "geotiffs")

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

# Define the Lambert93 coordinate system
lambert93 = osr.SpatialReference()
lambert93.ImportFromEPSG(2154)
transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:2154", "EPSG:4326", always_xy=True)

def apply_colormap(data_array, global_min, global_max):
    # Normalize the data using the global min and max
    norm_data = (data_array - global_min) / (global_max - global_min)

    # Apply the terrain colormap and then convert to 8-bit RGB
    colored = plt.cm.terrain(norm_data)
    return (colored[:, :, :3] * 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Step 1: Determine global min and max elevation values
global_min = float('inf')
global_max = float('-inf')

for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".asc"):
        input_path = os.path.join(source_folder, filename)
        input_dataset = gdal.Open(input_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
        data_array = input_dataset.ReadAsArray()

        current_min = np.nanmin(data_array)
        current_max = np.nanmax(data_array)

        global_min = min(global_min, current_min)
        global_max = max(global_max, current_max)

        input_dataset = None

for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".asc"):
        input_path = os.path.join(source_folder, filename)
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename.replace(".asc", ".tif"))

        # Open the .asc file
        input_dataset = gdal.Open(input_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

        # Get georeferencing information
        geotransform = input_dataset.GetGeoTransform()

        # Read the data and apply colormap
        data_array = input_dataset.ReadAsArray()
        rgb_array = apply_colormap(data_array, global_min, global_max)

        # Create an RGB output dataset
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
        output_dataset = driver.Create(output_path, input_dataset.RasterXSize, input_dataset.RasterYSize, 3,
                                       gdal.GDT_Byte)

        # Set georeferencing information
        output_dataset.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
        output_dataset.SetProjection(lambert93.ExportToWkt())

        # Write the RGB data to the output dataset
        for band in range(3):
            output_dataset.GetRasterBand(band + 1).WriteArray(rgb_array[:, :, band])

        # Close datasets
        input_dataset = None
        output_dataset = None

# Create KMZ
kml = simplekml.Kml()

for filename in os.listdir(output_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".tif"):
        geotiff_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)

        dataset = gdal.Open(geotiff_path)
        geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

        xllcorner = geotransform[0]
        yllcorner = geotransform[3]
        xurcorner = xllcorner + geotransform[1] * dataset.RasterXSize
        yurcorner = yllcorner + geotransform[5] * dataset.RasterYSize

        xll_wgs84, yll_wgs84 = transformer.transform(xllcorner, yllcorner)
        xur_wgs84, yur_wgs84 = transformer.transform(xurcorner, yurcorner)

        groundoverlay = kml.newgroundoverlay(name=f"Elevation Overlay - {filename}")
        groundoverlay.icon.href = filename
        groundoverlay.latlonbox.north = yur_wgs84
        groundoverlay.latlonbox.south = yll_wgs84
        groundoverlay.latlonbox.east = xur_wgs84
        groundoverlay.latlonbox.west = xll_wgs84

temp_kml_path = os.path.join(output_folder, "combined_elevation.kml")
kml.save(temp_kml_path)

with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(output_folder, "combined_elevation.kmz"), 'w') as kmz:
    kmz.write(temp_kml_path, "combined_elevation.kml")
    for geotiff_file in os.listdir(output_folder):
        if geotiff_file.endswith(".tif"):
            kmz.write(os.path.join(output_folder, geotiff_file), geotiff_file)

os.remove(temp_kml_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ChatGPT Lambert93 is for a flat surface and WGS84 for a sphere, using GDAL transformation did the trick:

```
for geotif_filename in geotif_filenames:
    # Reproject from Lambert-93 to WGS84
    lambert93 = osr.SpatialReference()
    lambert93.ImportFromEPSG(2154)

    wgs84 = osr.SpatialReference()
    wgs84.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

    reprojection_tmp_file_path = "" # empty to use the MEM driver and not create a file on disc
    ds = gdal.Warp(reprojection_tmp_file_path, geotif_filename, format="MEM", srcSRS=lambert93, dstSRS=wgs84)

    # Convert reprojected GeoTIFF to PNG
    tmp_png = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(geotif_filename))[0] + "_overlay.png"
    options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='PNG', noData=0)
    gdal.Translate(tmp_png, ds, options=options)
    png_files.append(tmp_png)

    # Extract georeferencing info for KML
    geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres = geotransform
    lrx = ulx + (ds.RasterXSize * xres)
    lry = uly + (ds.RasterYSize * yres)
```

[image]